# How do I merge duplicate rows and sum the amount column while keeping the dataframe structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge duplicate rows in my data frame and sum the amount column. But I want to keep the structure of my data frame intact.

The important columns I want to sum based on is 'report_name', 'line_item', 'column_item'. But I want to avoid summing column_item 30 and 50.

As an example the following would sum the amount column:

```
'report_name':C_72_00_a , 'line_item': 10, 'column_item': 10
'report_name':C_72_00_a , 'line_item': 10, 'column_item': 10
```

but this would not sum the amount column:

```
'report_name':C_72_00_a , 'line_item': 10, 'column_item': 10
'report_name':C_72_00_a , 'line_item': 10, 'column_item': 40
```

This is my data frame:

```
entity;business_line_group;conso_level_entity;report_name;line_item;column_item;z_axis;value_text;amount;approval_text
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;50;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;40409261.0100539;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;40;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;46860662.1948734;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;60;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;1783648.53838003;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;70;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;7847645.76582712;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;310;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;48100909.2077918;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;201;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;45652287.0078367;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;590;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;19988230.281333;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;480;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;28243908.6235795;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;490;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;12655653.8647408;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;530;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;27792100.4510517;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;570;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;20768476.5051213;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;480;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;28601515.4535418;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;490;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;17269663.9202129;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;530;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;21250486.2477187;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;570;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;12924566.8399212;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;110;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;17299383.641137;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;35;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;19054145.8837998;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;280;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;294348.91379545;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;340;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;40803729.9712868;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;240;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;25387904.3875074;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;340;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;6951075.43742419;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;240;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;12298844.1430509;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;40;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;50;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;60;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;70;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;90;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;110;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;240;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.85;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;260;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.85;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;80;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;100;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;120;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;130;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;140;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.95;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;150;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;170;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.8;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;190;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.93;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;200;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.88;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;250;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.85;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;270;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.85;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;280;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.85;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;290;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.8;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;320;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;330;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;340;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.7;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;350;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.65;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;360;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;370;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;380;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;390;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;400;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;410;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.7;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;420;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.65;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;430;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.6;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;440;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.45;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;450;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;460;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;40;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;70;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.15;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;90;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.03;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;110;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.1;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;260;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;310;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;480;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;490;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.1;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;530;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;570;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;590;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;80;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;140;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;150;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;170;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;190;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;200;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;250;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.2;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;280;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.2;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;290;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.1;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;360;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;370;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;380;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;390;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;400;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;420;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;430;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;450;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;35;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;180;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;204;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;206;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.2;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;207;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;220;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;230;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;300;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;510;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;520;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.1;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;540;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;560;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;600;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.3;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;610;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;630;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.1;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;640;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;660;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;670;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.3;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;680;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;700;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;710;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;890;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;900;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;913;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;914;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;915;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;916;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;917;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;918;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;940;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;950;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;960;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;970;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;980;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;990;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1000;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1010;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1030;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1040;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.07;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1050;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.15;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1060;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1070;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.3;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1080;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.35;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1090;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1100;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;40;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;60;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;70;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;90;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;201;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.2;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;260;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;80;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;130;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;150;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;170;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;190;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;180;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;230;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;160;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;210;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;269;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;273;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.07;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;277;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.15;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;281;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;285;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.3;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;289;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.35;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;293;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;301;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;303;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;309;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;313;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.07;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;317;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.15;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;321;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;325;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.3;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;329;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.35;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;333;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;341;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;343;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;345;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;70;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;5198630.14;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;190;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;835892217.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;260;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;4745984333.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;35;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;25424822307.28;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;70;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;-33216232069.67;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;80;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;-20966122130.53;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;110;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;-9384698955.8;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;230;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;2193605666.84;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;250;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;-573769151.28;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;260;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;3333715453.55;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;918;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;124366.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;160;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;-54345799619.07;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;260;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;150348.16;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1100;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;-37633449687.15;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1100;20;UNDEFINED;n/a;-3764349687.15;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1040;40;UNDEFINED;n/a;33764349687.15;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1045;40;UNDEFINED;n/a;33764349687.15;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1045;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;335098209.05;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1040;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;7449687.15;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1045;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;76449687.15;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;50;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;40409261.0100539;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;40;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;46860662.1948734;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;60;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;1783648.53838003;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;70;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;7847645.76582712;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;310;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;48100909.2077918;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;201;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;45652287.0078367;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;590;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;19988230.281333;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;480;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;28243908.6235795;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;490;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;12655653.8647408;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;530;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;27792100.4510517;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;570;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;20768476.5051213;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;480;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;28601515.4535418;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;490;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;17269663.9202129;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;530;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;21250486.2477187;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;570;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;12924566.8399212;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;110;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;17299383.641137;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;35;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;19054145.8837998;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;280;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;294348.91379545;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;340;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;40803729.9712868;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;240;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;25387904.3875074;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;340;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;6951075.43742419;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;240;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;12298844.1430509;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;40;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;50;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;60;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;70;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;90;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;110;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;240;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.85;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;260;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.85;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;80;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;100;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;120;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;130;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;140;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.95;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;150;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;170;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.8;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;190;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.93;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;200;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.88;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;250;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.85;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;270;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.85;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;280;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.85;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;290;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.8;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;320;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;330;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;340;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.7;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;350;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.65;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;360;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;370;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;380;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;390;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;400;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;410;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.7;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;420;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.65;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;430;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.6;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;440;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.45;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;450;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;460;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;40;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;70;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.15;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;90;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.03;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;110;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.1;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;260;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;310;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;480;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;490;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.1;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;530;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;570;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;590;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;80;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;140;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;150;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;170;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;190;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;200;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;250;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.2;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;280;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.2;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;290;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.1;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;360;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;370;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;380;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;390;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;400;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;420;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;430;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;450;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;35;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;180;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;204;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;206;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.2;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;207;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;220;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;230;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;300;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;510;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;520;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.1;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;540;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;560;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;600;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.3;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;610;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;630;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.1;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;640;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;660;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;670;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.3;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;680;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.4;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;700;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.75;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;710;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;890;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;900;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;913;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;914;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;915;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;916;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;917;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;918;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;940;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;950;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;960;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;970;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;980;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;990;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1000;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1010;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1030;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1040;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.07;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1050;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.15;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1060;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1070;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.3;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1080;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.35;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1090;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1100;50;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;40;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;60;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;70;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;90;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;201;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.2;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;260;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;80;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;130;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.05;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;150;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;170;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;190;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;180;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;230;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;160;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;210;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;269;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;273;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.07;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;277;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.15;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;281;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;285;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.3;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;289;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.35;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;293;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;301;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;303;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;309;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;313;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.07;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;317;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.15;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;321;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.25;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;325;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.3;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;329;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.35;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;333;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;341;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;0.5;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;343;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;345;80;UNDEFINED;n/a;1.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;70;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;5198630.14;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;190;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;835892217.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_72_00_a;260;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;4745984333.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;35;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;25424822307.28;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;70;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;-33216232069.67;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;80;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;-20966122130.53;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;110;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;-9384698955.8;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;230;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;2193605666.84;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;250;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;-573769151.28;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;260;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;3333715453.55;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;918;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;124366.0;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;160;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;-54345799619.07;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_74_00_a;260;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;150348.16;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1100;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;-37633449687.15;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1100;20;UNDEFINED;n/a;-3764349687.15;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1040;40;UNDEFINED;n/a;33764349687.15;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1045;40;UNDEFINED;n/a;33764349687.15;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1045;30;UNDEFINED;n/a;335098209.05;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1040;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;7449687.15;21/03/2022
456;test;456;C_73_00_a;1045;10;UNDEFINED;n/a;76449687.15;21/03/2022
```

I hope you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

please try this:

```
df['amount_sum'] = df.groupby(['report_name','line_item','column_item'])['amount'].transform('sum')
```